# dynamicaly add menu itmes to asp:Menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspmenu

I have a defined asp:Menu in design time in the master page.

I want to in the master page code behind in the page-load event a check that if the user is in the developer role, then they will get an additional set of menu items.

how do i use c# to add menu items from the code behind to the asp:menu?

i am not using a site map provider!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place this in your code behind:

```
Menu1.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Text", "Value"));
```

Comment: how about the url where to link the menu item to? where does this info go?

Comment: @kacalapy - that really depends on your code - if you view the html source, what do you see as the values of your other items? Are they URLS? If they are, then likely they go in the "value" field.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes MSDN is your best bet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5(VS.80).aspx - all about the Menu control :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a sitemap provider to populate your Menu?

If so, add a roles attribute to all the nodes you want displaying if a user is a Developer.

E.g.

```
<siteMapNode title="Home" url="~/Developer/Default.aspx" roles="Developer" />
```

Then in your Menu ItemDataBound event carry out a check to see if logged in user is a developer. The appropriate nodes will be displayed.